# post_type_link filter causes 404 on the CPT page it's used on

Tags: custom-post-types, plugins, permalinks, filters

When i change the permalink of my CPT using filters it gives a 404. I clicked save in the permalinks settings and switched and saved, but there's still a 404.  Is there some kind of hooking up i need to do with a rewrite to make this work?

```
function my_permalinks($permalink, $post, $leavename) {
    $post_id = $post->ID;
    if($post->post_type != 'model-list' || empty($permalink) || in_array($post->post_status, array('draft', 'pending', 'auto-draft')))
        return $permalink;
    $parent = $post->post_parent;
    $parent_post = get_post( $parent );
    $permalink = str_replace('model-list/', '', $permalink);
    return $permalink;
}
add_filter('post_type_link', 'my_permalinks', 10, 3);
```

the url is looking correct, but it gives a 404

Answer (score 3):

[`post_type_link`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/post_type_link) is a filter that is applied to the URL for a post before it’s returned by `get_post_permalink`.

So it doesn’t change any rewrite rules and the structure of permalinks is still the same.

So yeah - if you use it to change the structure of links, you have also to change the rewrite rules in such way, that the new link is matched and processed correctly.

Comment: ok thank you, but what should i put in add_rewrite_rule ?

Comment: i am removing the CPT name from the url, so i don't think I can find it on index.php because the permalink doesn't contain post_type info

Comment: i used this guide to try and do it https://1fix.io/blog/2016/02/05/parent-from-another-cpt/  i set the CPT to have a page that's a parent, it actually works if i don't set the parent

Comment: @TintinabulatorZea if you’re removing CPT name, then it won’t be so easy to match these posts using only rewrite rules - these patterns will cause conflicts (there is no way to tell if WP should look for your CPT or a normal page). In such case you have to write some custom code that will check what type of post to search for and get that post. There’s a good answer on how to remove CPT slug from URL somewhere in here (I’m on mobile currently, so it’s not so easy for me to find it, sorry)